# Calling Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension with -Role failing with "extension ID ... is invalid"

Tags: powershell, azure

This is not a duplicate of [Calling Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension with Role parameter fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743536/calling-set-azureservicediagnosticsextension-with-role-parameter-fails). That particular issue was related to having dots in the role name which has been fixed.

Based on the version number showing in "Programs and Features" I'm running 0.9.1 of the Azure Powershell. I installed it yesterday (2015/05/13) using the Web Platform Installer. The script I'm executing is:

```
$storage_name = "mystorageaccountname"
$key = "mykey"
$service_name = "cwagner-ipseity-worker"
$public_config = "C:\tfs\SI\ipseity\trunk\BuildArtifacts\Deployment\Packages\AzureWorker\PaaSDiagnostics.Ipseity.Server.MessageProcessor.AzureWorkerRole.PubConfig.xml" 
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_name -StorageAccountKey $key
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storageContext -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath $public_config -ServiceName $service_name -Slot Production -Role Ipseity.Server.MessageProcessor.AzureWorkerRole
```

I get the following output:

```
VERBOSE: Setting PaaSDiagnostics configuration for Ipseity.Server.MessageProcessor.AzureWorkerRole.
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension : BadRequest: The extension ID IpseityServerMessageProcessorAzureWorkerRole-PaaSDiagnostics-Production-Ext-0 is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -StorageContext $storgeContext -Diagnostics ...
+ > ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Hyak.Common.CloudException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.Extensions.
```

SetAzureServiceDiagnosticsExtensionCommand

If we don't specify the `-Role` parameter it works.

Answer (score 0):

The Extension ID is too long.
One option is to rename the role.

Comment: Is there a document that describes the restrictions on Extension IDs? Such as length, allowed characters, etc?

Comment: Most identifier must be between 3 to 24 characters. You can look into the docs at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-create-storage-account or to get more insights on troubleshooting at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors